# asp.net gridview event , keeping datasource

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datasource

whats are methods to keeping datasource for a gridview.

situation :

I have a query which can take 5 to 10 seconds (a lot of link on a lot of data).
The result is too big for a page so I have a paging on my grid.

But, every time I use the `pageIndexChanged`, I need to get the datasource again.

So I want to know how I can keep my datasource.

Is it possible? **NOT by session**.

Comment: tank you Tarun for your english improvement

Comment: How are you databinding?  It should be automatically persisting the data source setup via the viewstate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, I have used a custom (server-side) viewstate provider to cache your datasource.

****Updated:***  There is a pretty good article on custom viewstate providers (with sample code) here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8001/ViewState-Provider-an-implementation-using-Provide

However, I would strongly recommend improving your query to limit the data to that which the user really wants to see.  Large grids that have many more rows than the user is truly interested in are unwieldy from memory, processor, bandwidth, and user-experience perspectives.  Try to find a better way.

Comment: I did that, but he Can have more than 10000lines. I need to search between tables with 100000lines. I linked 20 tables. at the end, it can take times. And I cant create Sql SP or Fct (inside rules)

Comment: working for small data, but with much data, viewstate cause errors. I search the way to solve it.

Comment: The standard viewstate will not work for very large data, but the custom viewstate providers (persist to file or DB) will handle the large data.  I've used it to handle > 50,000 rows.  As I originally mentioned, it is probably better to have the user supply search criteria to filter the data BEFORE populating a grid with more data than they will actually use.  Very rarely is a grid containing thousands of rows actually meaningful to the end user.  A large grid of data forces them to use other, less friendly, ways to filter through the grid to find what they are actually looking for.

Comment: I use the viewstate with compression (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14733/ViewState-Compression). And I also review my data, remove unessary data)